# xpath for no tag elements

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

`<span class="uniqueid">abc</span>"efg"`

How can I get the value of efg using XPath? I am able to get abc by `//span[@class="uniqueid"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `following-sibling::text()` predicate in your xpath expression.

Here is an example:

```py
from lxml import html

hstr = '<div><span class="uniqueid">abc</span>"efg"</div>'

h = html.fromstring(hstr)
h.xpath('//span[@class="uniqueid"]/following-sibling::text()')
# returns:
['"efg"']
```